# How to update DNS Zone for a static domain

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, cache, cdn, cpanel

I am running this site: www.thetechnofreaks.com on Wordpress.

Recently I came across a plugin that claims to increase the page load efficiency of my site. the plugin details can be found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/installation/

Now the plugin mentions a self-hosted method for CDN which is known as pipelining. It states:

> If you do not have a CDN provider, you can still improve your site's performance using the "Self-hosted" method. On your own server, create a subdomain and matching DNS Zone record; e.g. static.domain.com and configure FTP options on the "Content Delivery Network" tab accordingly. Be sure to FTP upload the appropriate files, using the available upload buttons.

Now I have created a static.thetechnofreaks.com sub-domain but I don't know how to enter matching DNS Zone record and configure FTP options.

Please guide me in this regard. I went to my cPanel -> Simple DNS Zone Editor. It contains:

> Add an A Record
>
> Name:
>   Address:
>
> Add a CNAME Record
>
> Name:
>   CNAME:

What am I supposed to enter in this??

Comment: +1 for W3TC plugin - it's not for the feint-hearted, but the results are pretty amazing if you get it set-up right.

Answer (score 2):

Pipelining, or using a cookie-free subdomain to [enable concurrent downloads](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-subdomains.html) of static/cached items (like CSS/JS) is [a really good idea](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free).

You didn't actually have to create a sub-domain to enable this approach (but there's nothing wrong about doing such), all you needed to do was [create a CNAME record](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/) for `static.example.com` and ensure this "points" to your `www.example.com`, so to answer your question:

> Name: static.example.com
>   CNAME: www.example.com

You don't need to add anything to the A Record box.

There's a few other good tips in the last link (e.g. ensuring cookies aren't accidentally set using Google Analytics, and some other WordPress specific stuff.)